# Daily alarm issue, Calendar.DATE and Calendar.DAYS_OF_MONTH difference

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to implement alarm that notify daily at the same time. It works fine. But when i set alarm again it notify me on the spot without waiting time to come, because time on which alarm is set has been passed. But when I change `Calendar.DATE` to `Calendar.DAYS_OF_MONTH` it does not notify me. So can any one help me where i am wrong. I am sharing my code below.

```
       public void setNotification() {
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = createPendingIntent();

        Calendar calendarToSet=Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar currentTime=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarToSet.set(Calendar.HOUR,10);
        calendarToSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        calendarToSet.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        calendarToSet.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

        if(calendarToSet.before(currentTime))
        {
            calendarToSet.set(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MyAppManager.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendarToSet.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
       // Toast.makeText(MyAppManager.context, "set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

        public PendingIntent createPendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyAppManager.context, TaffaquhFiddinBroadCastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", "What_to_say_upon_completing_ablution");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyAppManager.context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;

    }
```

What i am trying to do is to set alarm for the next day if the time is passed so please help.

Also what is the difference between `Calendar.DATE` and `Calendar.DAYS_OF_MONTH`?

Comment: look at user13 answer. With `set`, you set the day of month, which  in your case is the first (example 01.01.). With `add` you just add one day to the current calendar day.

Comment: So using set . Sets my date to Day 1 of the month? If so then why it notify me on the spot without waiting day 1 to come

Comment: yes it does and android´s alarmManager allways starts if the date you currently set is in the past...that´s why you immediately get the alarm...

Comment: So thats why it notify me every time i set alarm.

Comment: If i did not understand it wrong it will wait for the first day of month, because i am using repeating and AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY

Comment: I´ll never tried it, but logically your code does exact this if you use `set`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are *setting* the day field of your `Calendar` instance, instead of *adding* a day to it.

Change the following:

```
calendarToSet.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

To this:

```
calendarToSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

> Also what is the difference between `Calendar.DATE` and
>   `Calendar.DAYS_OF_MONTH`?

They are the same, `DATE` is just a synonym for `DAY_OF_MONTH`.

From the source code of the `Calendar` class:

```
public static final int DATE = 5;
public static final int DAY_OF_MONTH = 5;
```

As you can see, they represent the same value.

Comment: What is difference  between Calendar.Date and Calendar.Days_Of_Month?

Comment: Thanks it was really help full

Comment: yes DATE and DAY_OF_MONTH are the same. For whatever reason Google has implemented two Constants with the same value....